# A set of random values in an int array of a user specified size

Tags: java, jcreator

Write a method to generate and return a set of random values in an int array of a user specified size. The values should all be between +/- N, where N is a constant such as 100.
Thank you.
Here's Mine;

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int limit, numbers;
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter your limit value for your array: ");           //Needs to be positive.
        limit = scan.nextInt();

        int[] list = new int[limit];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
        }

        numbers = random.nextInt(limit - (0 - limit)) + (0 - limit);
        System.out.println (numbers);

        System.out.println (list[numbers]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include what you have tried?

Comment: You can ask us help. But you can't order us write code, unless you pay.

Comment: We are not here to do your assignment for you. Please post the code you have written so far and a more specific question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. Here I used edit.

Comment: Okay. Now what is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: it does not work properly. I would like t create an array by user given limit and it needs to be between -limit and limit such as -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3 and I would like to take a value randomly from these numbers lets say -2 and 3. And lastly I would like to print my array and the random values seperately.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Math.Random()?

Comment: There is no restriction I think :) so, we can use.

Comment: then answer is given below. Good lk

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Integer> random(int range, int count){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(Math.random() > 0.5){
            //adding positive value with probability of 0.5
            result.add((int)(Math.random() * (double)range));
        }else{
            //adding negative value with probability of 0.5
            result.add(-1 * (int)(Math.random() * (double)range));
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

If you want to create your own random number generator, the easiest one to implement will be Linear Congruential Generator. Read from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) and try yourself. Ask here if you need help.